# How can I set up my site to use Google Apps for Domains via cPanel

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, g-suite-administrator, cpanel

Not an issue I have now, luckily, as I've switched hosts, but this annoyed me for a while.

I had a site hosted with a host who did not give me a DNS control panel, just cPanel. Is there a way using cPanel to set up Google Apps for Domains for email?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about setting up an email service are off-topic in Web Applications SE. They might be on topic in [webmasters.se] and [sf].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ZoneEdit](http://www.zoneedit.com). You get 5 free Zones.

When you sign up and add a domain you will be given 2 nameservers.

Replicate your host's existing DNS entries in ZoneEdit.

Add/Update the MX records etc to Google Apps.

Point your domain at the ZoneEdit nameservers.

Wait up to 72 hours for the changes to propagate around DNS.

My host (FastHosts in the UK) does not support advanced DNS settings so I currently have 7 domains in ZoneEdit to allow me to use Google Apps.

Answer (score 1):

CPanel should allow you to add CNAME records for verification and aliasing.  I believe it is under aliases or subdomains in CPanel.

For MX records, they usually have an option for that, in some instances, I believe it only allowed me to enter a single MX entry, but that is sufficient to get Apps up and working, you just lose a bit of redundancy.  Look for "DNS Record" or "MX Entry" or possibly just "Email" or "Mail" on the CPanel icons.  I don't have one available that I can reference or I would have slightly more confidence in the names of the options.